# Как сделать Button в Activity - рисовалке (GraphicsView/Draw2D)?

Tags: java, android, button, графика

Полистав страницы интернета "молодой падаван" понял что любую графику рисуют в новом классе наследуемом от View и создают объект в классе Draw2d (или GraphicsView). В любом случае без разметки.xml Но как тогда использовать Button-ы и другие View-шки разметки на том же activity где и рисуют графику?

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это первое, что увидит пользователь запустив приложение. А теперь, по-задумке:

1. Вместо серого фона сделать анимирование изображение, например, падающих листьев.
2. По клику на кнопку "GO" осуществляется переход на новую Activity (со своей разметкой Button-ов) но с сохранением анимации падающих листьев + происходит прорисовка дополнительных элементов графики (например: как эти листья сдувает ветром).

Так вот если создавать новый класс для отрисовки тех же листьев и анимации ветра, то как втулить туда кнопки?

P.S: использую стандартные библиотеки Android Studio (нет AndEngine, Unity, libGDX)

Answer (score 0):

Всё это (фон, листь, кнопки) подключается как правило через лайоут (по умолчанию это res\layout\activity_main.xml)